# Most intuitive path to rep point privilege list

Tags: support, help-center, navigation

On any given SE network site, what's the sanest click path to get to that page that shows you what privileges you get at various reputation levels?

https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges

I can never seem to find it quickly when I'm looking for it. The way I just now found the one on SO was:

1. Click my reputation score in the nav bar to go to my user page.
2. Click one of my badges on the summary page.
3. Click privileges on the right.

This is easy, only 3 clicks, no problem with that, but for some reason I can never remember this path (I only refer to that page very rarely) and it actually took me quite some time just now and some dead-end clicks to get there. I also access it rarely enough that even though "/help/privileges" is pretty obvious, I never really recall it.

Is there a more intuitive route to this page?

Comment: The privileges link in your profile (next to edit and preferences) will take you there in one less click

Comment: @JonK Perfect! I don't know why I never saw that there. In fact, that whole area of the profile page seems to be in my blind spot for some reason. As obvious as that is, want to post it as an answer?

Comment: I always click "help" --> "Help Center" --> "View a full list of privileges you can earn". Still three clicks, but more intuitive.

Comment: (Incidentally: Whoa; flair? That's kinda cool.)

Comment: @Jason 3.5 years in SO and only now you find out about the flair? ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I know! I always felt there was something missing in my online life! P.S. Good help center tip; that's another easy one to remember - to be honest I usually glaze over those links and just type my question - which actually works for "privileges" but indirectly (none of the topics are the privilege list but clicking on the "Privileges" category goes there).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The privileges link in your profile gets you there a click faster!

[image]

Comment: Nice FHRC, now you're 10 rep closer to new privilege! ;)

Comment: That *is* a good circle, slight overshoot and a pointy corner, but the full closure, clean lack of cross-over, and near-perfect convexity more than makes up for it.

Comment: @JasonC Since the new style profiles have been added this route doesn't exist anymore. You can still use your old route though. Might be easiest just to remember that the link is `/help/privileges` and manually type the URL... There **is** another route through the profile but it's 4 clicks (profile > click the "Next privilege" progress bar > learn more > privileges).